# Exclude git ignore on one particular directory inside an already gitignored directory

Tags: git, visual-studio

My gitignore file currently looks like the following:

```
# Visual Studio 2015 cache/options directory
.vs/
# Uncomment if you have tasks that create the project's static files in wwwroot
#wwwroot/
**/wwwroot/lib/
**/wwwroot/_references.js
**/wwwroot/app/**/*.js*
**/wwwroot/css/**/*.min.css
**/wwwroot/js/**/*.min.js
**/wwwroot/bundles/**/*.bundle.min.js
```

Basically I want to ignore all files within the `wwwroot/lib/` directory with the exception of a particular directory within lib: `/wwwroot/lib/file-tester`

How can I do this with `.gitignore`? I've read about the exclamation mark syntax but it's not working, possibly due to the ordering of ignoring. I tried it like the following:

```
# Visual Studio 2015 cache/options directory
.vs/
# Uncomment if you have tasks that create the project's static files in wwwroot
#wwwroot/
**/wwwroot/lib/
!/wwwroot/lib/file-tester
**/wwwroot/_references.js
**/wwwroot/app/**/*.js*
**/wwwroot/css/**/*.min.css
**/wwwroot/js/**/*.min.js
**/wwwroot/bundles/**/*.bundle.min.js
```

But it didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First off, I am not sure why you are overusing **.  If you have one directory /wwwroot/lib, you can ignore it just with:

```
/wwwroot/lib/
```

As for your negation of the directory, I think you just need to specify that it IS a directory you are referring to, with the ending backslash:

```
!/wwwroot/lib/file-tester/
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because you exclude whole `/wwwroot/lib/` directory instead of it's content. Patterns for ignoring this directory should look like this:

```
/wwwroot/lib/*
!/wwwroot/lib/file-tester
```

Answer (score 0):

#### /* to the rescue

A slight variation of the directory exclude syntax is useful here:

```
$ cat .gitignore
wwwroot/lib/*
!wwwroot/lib/file-tester
```

Notice the trailing `/*` which is significant and tells git to exclude everything inside the lib folder but not the lib folder itself. The nuance is that if the first line were `wwwroot/lib` instead, that tells git to ignore the `wwwroot/lib` directory itself and then no 'un-exclude' patterns will have any effect. Instead with the trailing `/*`, we convey to git to exclude the contents of the directory allowing a subsequent exclude pattern to work. I have tested this to work, as seen below:

```
# Create a directory which should be excluded
$ mkdir -p wwwroot/lib/dir-to-exclude && touch wwwroot/lib/dir-to-exclude/empty.txt

# Now confirm that the above directory, file is not tracked by git
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
    .gitignore
    wwwroot/lib/file-tester/empty2.txt
```

(Tested on git v. 2.10.0)

#### Checking which rule is excluding a file

```
$ git check-ignore -v wwwroot/lib/dir-to-exclude
.gitignore:1:wwwroot/lib/*  wwwroot/lib/dir-to-exclude
```

---

Using the exclamation syntax with directory exclusion, what you are trying to achieve:

> Basically I want to ignore all files within the wwwroot/lib/ directory with the exception of a particular directory within lib: /wwwroot/lib/file-tester

is NOT possible.

From https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore:

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. **It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.** Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined. Put a backslash ("\") in front of the first "!" for patterns that begin with a literal "!", for example, "!important!.txt".

If you exclude `wwwroot/lib`, then it is no longer possible to include any of it's sub-directories by doing a `!wwwroot/lib/file-tester`.  I have tested this on a test repository and can confirm this:

```
$ touch wwwroot/lib/file-tester/empty2.txt

$ cat .gitignore
!wwwroot/lib/file-tester
wwwroot/lib

$ git status
Untracked files:
    .gitignore

$ vim .gitignore #Edited to remove wwwroot/lib
$ cat .gitignore
!wwwroot/lib/file-tester

$ git status
Untracked files:
    .gitignore
    wwwroot/lib/file-tester/empty2.txt
```

(This was tested on https://github.com/ajorpheus/git-ignore-test)
Notice that as soon as the `wwwroot/lib` is removed, the file `wwwroot/lib/file-tester/empty2.txt` starts being recognized by git as an un-tracked file.

Answer (score 0):

Below definition works.

```
**/wwwroot/lib
**/wwwroot/lib/*.*
```