# *.aar files been ignored by git

Tags: android, git, version-control, gitignore

I want to push my *.aar files to git but, git is no allowing that, here goes my folder structure:

```
#Main .gitignore


# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Android Studio Navigation editor temp files
.navigation/

# Android Studio captures folder
captures/
```

Here goes the second git ignore:

```
#earth/.gitignore   <-- This is the directory where gitignore file is
!build/
```

3RD:

```
#earth/build/.gitignore   <-- This is the directory where gitignore file is
!outputs/
```

4TH

```
#earth/build/outputs/.gitignore   <-- This is the directory where gitignore file is
!aar/
```

And inside aar folder are my files, but they never appear. Ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Is the `earth` folder ignored anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following to check which rule is excluding a file:

```
$ git check-ignore -v path-to-an-aar
```

---

Also, note that, including a subdirectory after excluding its parent is NOT possible. From https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore:

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. **It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.** Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined. Put a backslash ("\") in front of the first "!" for patterns that begin with a literal "!", for example, "!important!.txt".

However, not all hope is lost. Take a look at [Exclude git ignore on one particular directory inside an already gitignored directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523970/exclude-git-ignore-on-one-particular-directory-inside-an-already-gitignored-dire/39580233#39580233)

Comment: Great! In my case was a `/User/[MyName]/.gitignore_global` that was excluding my `Build` directory for every projects. Thank you @ashotosh-jindal, you save my day!